# Regex two given words in one sentence

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get a regex which can tell if two given words are in one sentence (word order matters). The problem is that I can have a contraction in a sentence, so the period doesn't indicate that there's the end of the sentence. The part of regex which indicates the end of the sentence is

```
\\.(\s+[A-Z]|\s*$)
```

What would the pattern look like?

Comment: show an example of a string you want to match.

Comment: I can identify the end of the sentence by the following part of regex: \.(\s+[A-Z]|\s*$)

Comment: My apologies. Stupid question deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this:

```
(\b\w+\b)(?:[^.]|\.\s)*(\b\w+\b)
```

This basically says, match and capture a word, then anything that is not a period, or a period followed b a space, any number of times, and finally match and capture another word.

**EDIT:** For *given* words in either order, use:

```
(\bWord1\b)(?:[^.]|\.\s)*(\bWord2\b)|(\bWord2\b)(?:[^.]|\.\s)*(\bWord1\b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not c#, but you should get the idea

```
for sentence in split_text_with_regex(text):
    index_word1 = sentence.find(word1)
    index_word2 = sentence.find(word2)
    # do your thing
```

Comment: Is it possible to costruct one regex with no for's?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good set of options available here http://www.regular-expressions.info/near.html

Comment: the link is helpfull but it doesn't solve my problem as far as \W might match a period.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can construct the regular expression in Visual Studio itself . Refer to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(VS.80).aspx first paragraph

Answer (score 0):

So I think it's something like this (untested):

```
(([\w\s]*\s)?Word1\s([\w\s]*)?\sWord2(\s[\w\s]*)?\.)(?=(\s+[A-Z]|\s*$))
```

Edit: Thinking about it, that won't match punctuation (commas, apostrophes).  Perhaps each [\w\s] should be [^\.] or a list of possible characters.